# Minicart starts Spinning after few days on adding product

Tags: magento2, checkout, mini-cart

I am Using my `Own custom theme` extended from `LUMA` theme and in that I have extended **checkout module**, done some modifications like bringing `CHECKOUT` button in the bottom as it comes at the top.

Added `minicart` `auto_open` functionality when a customer click on `add to cart` button, it works as follow:

[image]

Now, I keep spinning as below image and can't figure out the problem:

[image]

**Everything works great for few days** and then minicart stops working and **start spinning after clicking** on `add to cart` button.

I had tried few things to resolve this issue:

- Roll back the changes I have made to Checkout module ( problem don't go away)
- Restored the previous working backup and works fine and after few days again the same problem.

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation of hours and trying all the possible solution I didn't get any solution.

Then finally, I escalated this issue to the Hosting Provider ( NEXCESS ) and their support get it fixed because it was a server caching issue.

If anyone come across such kind of issue then make sure its not a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ajax` call you must be using these two functions-

Add below code in `beforeSend()` function:

```
      /*To hide loader on mini-cart*/
        $(".loading-mask").show();
        /*****************************/
```

Add below code in `success()` function:

```
   /*To hide loader on mini-cart*/
         setTimeout(function() {
            $(".loading-mask").hide();
         }, 3000);
    /*******************************/
```

add above code just before the function's body end.

I have used `setTimeout()` function to stop loader after mini-cart count increment.